# iOS - Scan QR code with camera - Option A: Go to installed application - Option B: Go to appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, app-store, qr-code

At this moment we have a feature build in our app that uses the normal iOS camera app for scanning a QR code. When this happens you will be redirected to the concerning app that's installed and not a certain webpage.

**Our question is:**
Is it possible to be redirected to the appstore, if you don't have the concerning app installed where this QR code is for?

I'm not a developer myself and only curious if its possible.
This for future expansions of our app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Firebase Dynamic Links [Firebase Dynamic Links: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/21376846-firebase-dynamic-links-getting-started)